# Change https:// link to short link of SharePoint

Tags: c#

I try to convert this link
https://sites.inside-share.bosch.com/sites/091650/default.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2F091650%2FDocuments%2FRadar%5FGen5%2F2020%2FPJDC%2FPJDC%2D44323%5Fper%5Fcold&FolderCTID=0x012000057B57E3646F2140BC08E3585BA3A2A0&View=%7BEBFBFE65%2D0A5F%2D425D%2DBA83%2DB2E0C52A7E3F%7D

to

https://sites.inside-share.bosch.com/sites/091650/Documents/Radar_Gen5/2020/PJDC/PJDC-44323_per_cold

I know that we can use something like a replace, remove some path of string to convert But I don't know is there any Sharepoint library support to convert or is there any ensure way to do that?

Comment: The link is a query with parameters.  The parameters are after the question mark.  So how can you leave out the parameters?

Comment: @jdweng that's called "URL routing" or "friendly URLs" and that has existed for a long time. The page you're currently on could as well have the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/index.php?view=questions&id=59612571&slug=change-https-link-to-short-link-of-sharepoint`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the RootFolder is your true path, so assuming `url` contains your url, then all you have to do is get the scheme and hostname and combine that with a URLDecoded version of RootFolder:

```cs
var uri = new Uri(url);
var rootFolder = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ParseQueryString()["RootFolder"]);
var newUrl = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + rootFolder;
```

Comment: Hi Bech, about the second line, I was try with it in both of vb.net and c# but there is no "uri.ParseQueryString()["RootFolder"]". Could you please help me check again.